# Node route response not setting

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, typeorm

Kinda new to node and typescript so need a little help.
Using node/express/postres as backend and https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm as orm which has a function to open connection which looks like that:

```
export declare function createConnection(): Promise<Connection>;
```

So when I want to use that in my route it looks like that:

```
    this.app.get("/test", function (req, res) {

        createConnection()
            .then(conn => {
                console.log("Start connection...");
                let repo = conn.getRepository(entForum);

                let obj = repo.find();
                conn.close().catch(err => { });
                return obj;
            })
            .then(data => {
                res.send(data);
            });

        console.log("Done");
    });
```

And the console output is :

```
Done
GET /test/ 200 51.053 ms - 1133
Start connection...
```

The problem is I'm getting 'Can't set headers after they are sent.'.
It looks like response is sent after console.log("DONE"); and then one more time in promise.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What if you return the whole promise there? And remove the console.log("DONE");. `return createConnection().then //etc etc etc`

Pretty sure since you're not returning the promise it's finishing the request before the database calls complete.

Comment: Don't know about the Can't set headers after they are sent bit, but your promise is executing after the done because you haven't tied them together correctly. You need to add a final `.then(() => console.log("DONE"))`

Comment: This error is often caused my faulty handling of async operations, but if this is really all your code in that route, I don't see any obvious problems here since there is only one place a response is sent here.  Are you sure there isn't more code in your real route handler?  Are you sure the problem is caused by this route handler?  FYI, in a normal route handler, you would not declare the `next` argument since it should only be used in middleware, not in endpoint handlers.

Comment: Added some console logs to show flow. And yes, this is the only code in my route

Comment: Do you have any earlier registered route/middleware that might call `send` and `next`? Because with the given code that might be the only plausible reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out what was wrong. Turns out the problem was this piece of code after the promise - `console.log("Done");`

If i remove that, everything works ok.

Comment: If `console.log("Done");` did output `Done` to the console, then it does not make sense that removing it would solve the problem, only if it would have thrown an error then it could have been the reason.